# How do I derive a transfer function of RC circuit including ESR?

Tags: transfer-function, bode-plot, pole-zeroplot

I am reading through some lecture and wondering how to derive transfer function when input source is a current source. Can you anyone give me an advice? Thank you

[image]

Comment: If you want the transfer function with respect to the current source, that's one thing. If you want the transfer function with respect to the control voltage, that's another thing. In the first case it's a transimpedance (V/A.) In the second case it is unitless (or V/V.) But which is it that you seek?

Comment: im asking the source as just current source.

Comment: This is pretty basic EE stuff -- are you saying that you don't know how to calculate the transfer function of _anything_ that has a current source as an input, or are you being tripped up by the fact that it's a capacitor with ESR, even though your schematic shows an accurate model for that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that the output voltage is defined across RL the transfer funktion Vout/Iin is nothing else than the input impedance of the RC-network.

**Vout/In=RL||(ESR + 1/sCo)**

**Vout/In=[RL + s * RL * ESR * Co]/[1 + sCo * (RL+ESR)]**

Answer (score 2):

> *I am reading through some lecture and wondering how to derive transfer
> function when input source is a current source*

Ignoring the fact that the input is a voltage...

Convert the VCCS to a VCVS by using the parallel resistor \$R_L\$. It's called a Thevenin/Norton theorem conversion i.e. every current source in parallel with a resistor can be made into a voltage source in series with the same value resistor.

Answer (score 2):

There are plenty of options to derive this transfer function which is a *transimpedance*. The first one is the brute-force approach: simply determine the impedance loading the current source by associating the load resistance and the \$RC\$ network in parallel. This will lead you to an expression you will have to rearrange for unveiling the pole and the zero. It is a so-called *high-entropy* expression because it is disorganized and does not show the poles and zeroes immediately.

The other option is to involve the fast analytical circuits techniques or FACTs as described in my last [book](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1960405195) on the subject. First off, determine the gain of this transfer function at dc, when \$s=0\$. Then, once done, turn the *excitation* off and "look" through the capacitor's connecting terminals to determine the resistance \$R\$ you "see". This resistance multiplied by the capacitor will generate the time constant of this circuit, \$\tau=RC\$. In a first-order system, the pole is the inverse of the time constant and thus \$\omega_p=\frac{1}{\tau}\$.

For the zero, you have to determine an impedance which is going to *null* the *response* - \$V_{out}\$ - collected across the load resistance. An impedance can null the response if it shunts a node to ground, preventing the excitation or stimulus from propagating through the network to produce an ac response, hence the *null* on the output. The frequency at which this impedance becomes a *transformed* short circuit is the zero you want. In this circuit, it is when \$r_C\$ and \$C\$ in series offer a 0-ohm resistance at \$s=s_z\$. Let's look at it with a picture summarizing these steps:

[image]

You can see how easy it is to determine this transimpedance without resorting to a line of algebra, just inspecting the intermediate sketches. You can start by applying the technique to 1st-order networks and see by yourself how powerful this approach is. It is guaranteed, once you've tasted - and tested - the FACTs, there is no going back!

Comment: Could it be possible to use the same approach as for poles, using time constant, to find the zeros?

Comment: Yes, absolutely: you turn the excitation off and determine the resistance driving the energy-storing elements (caps or inductors) for determining the time constants in the denominator. You would do the same by turning the excitation back on again and determine the resistance driving the energy-storing elements when the output is *nulled*. This is what is called a null double injection or NDI.